# Extract a letter from a cell and vlookup the value

Tags: excel

I have a cell which contains for example: `R001` but the column that has the data im searching it does not have the letter "R".

To solve this, i use the `extract` formula. I also tried the `right` formula, and works the same. Now that i have only numbers, i'm using a `vlookup` formula to search for the values but i have an error displaying *there is a value not available for this formula or function* so the cell contains "#N/A"

How i may solve this issue?

Here is the row where the first column is the data with the letter, the third column is the data without the letter.

[image]

Here is the column (A) from the next sheet where i need to look for the value:

[image]

Sorry i have the excel on spanish, so the formulas are also on spanish.

Substitute formula would be the "extract" that i'm referring to.

Comment: Right returns a string, if you are trying to compare that to real numbers, it will not find a match.  We need to see example of the lookup table to help.  You can try changing the string to a number by wrapping the `RIGHT` in `VALUE`: `VALUE(RIGHT(...,...))`

Comment: What do you mean with `Extract` formula? An UDF?

Comment: sample data or image of spreadsheet would be helpful

Comment: Worked with the `Value:`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical example that you may be able to adapt to your needs:

```
=VLOOKUP(--MID(A1,2,99),C1:D9,2,FALSE)
```

for this schema:

[image]

*(In the example above, I converted the lookup value to a number to match the values in column **C**; in your case, converting to a number may not be necessary)*

Answer (score 0):

I finished using `=IF(A2<>"";VALUE(TRIM(A2;2;13));"")` and works!

Thanks for the fast replies.